# How the first programming language and compiler was made?

Tags: microprocessor, binary

How to get access to processor?I know that our OS don't allow to do that. Can we delete our OS to get the access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather cumbersome. It was done in the very early stages of computers, That is why PDP computers have toggle switched on the front.

Nowadays it is as old fashioned as taking a flint stone, walk up to a tree and start making a cabinet.

---

I think a lot of people have no idea how much we owe to that generation which patiently, toggling switches, bootstrapped us to where we are now.

Comment: For those who can't follow my answer, the question has dramatically changed. It was: **How a processor is instructed in binary language?**
*How to write directly in binary language without any operating system installed.Means just using binary language without software like hex editor neo.*

Comment: Also interesting(?) to note that the PDP was so called because the UK did not permit the import of anything called a 'computer'. How times have changed!